# perfect Tabhost in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I need to create tabhost in Android application, but I have a doubt whether I should do it by using `Fragment` or `FragmentActivity` or only using `Activity`. I have checked this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) but still I didn't clear everything. I have seen this example, but I would still need some hints.

here is the code:

```
public class FragmentTabs extends FragmentActivity {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
                FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
                LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Custom"),
                LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Throttle"),
                LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class, null);
    }
}
```

So, could somebody help me out? @Thanks!

Comment: Please explain your question with more detail, I am not able to understand what's your issue?

Comment: @MKJParekh Actually i need to create tabhost in my app but i need how could i create it in a perfect way using fragment or fragmentactivity or only using activity

Comment: @priya check this link http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-fragment-tabs-in-android/

Comment: @ChiragPatel this app is not running below 13 http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-fragment-tabs-in-android/

Comment: @priya Its depends on your requirement, Fragment is a part of Activity

Comment: If you want to call a multiple child view in first second or in third tab then you can use fragment....

Comment: Because fragment is the part of activity.

Comment: So after many suggestions your problem solved or not?